# AWS lambda; docker image write & return files

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Put together a Docker Image running `Python 3.9` with some custom scripting inside. Basically, at the end of the program, it's supposed to return a `.xlsx` if all goes well, or a `.txt` with error logging and who to contact if things go bad.

The problem appears to be twofold:

1. On attempting to write, I get an error indicating that where I'm trying to write is `read-only`. I've seen other responses indicate that I get 500MB of temp space on lambda functions. What's up with this?
2. How would I pass the `.xlsx` or the `.txt` back through the gateway API, to be received by a user on the front-end? `AWS` documentation says stuff about going to the `API` and then clicking on settings, but I literally don't even see a settings button, so I'm failing on step 1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of writing on your local machine (inside docker where the code lives) you can try writing to S3. Then return the S3 uri to the user so he can access the file.

Comment: I don't hate this idea, except for the fact that this tool is customer facing. Is it possible to make a simple download link for S3 files? I've only ever interacted with S3 via CLI, with heavily controlled permissions.

Comment: Yes. you can enable public access on your bucket/objects and then anyone can download the files publicaly. Starting point would be: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/

Comment: Figured it out and ended up going this route. Thanks.